# StackOverFlowError on instance LoggerFactory.getLogger on a SessionBean

Tags: java, logging, stack-overflow, jboss7.x, slf4j

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11

I am getting java.lang.StackOverFlowError on the instance of LoggerFactory.getLogger but I have no clue why is that.
It is getting org.jboss.logmanner instead of org.slf4j, does it sound right?

**Error log**

```
08:50:58,787 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-1) Error Rendering View[/principal.xhtml]: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.callStackWalk(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.beginStackWalk(StackStreamFactory.java:370)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackStreamFactory$AbstractStackWalker.walk(StackStreamFactory.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.StackWalker.walk(StackWalker.java:498)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.JDKSpecific.findCallingClasses(JDKSpecific.java:72)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.ClassLoaderLogContextSelector$1.run(ClassLoaderLogContextSelector.java:93)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.ClassLoaderLogContextSelector$1.run(ClassLoaderLogContextSelector.java:91)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.ClassLoaderLogContextSelector.getLogContext(ClassLoaderLogContextSelector.java:121)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.ThreadLocalLogContextSelector.getLogContext(ThreadLocalLogContextSelector.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.logging@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.WildFlyLogContextSelectorImpl.getLogContext(WildFlyLogContextSelectorImpl.java:56)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext.getLogContext(LogContext.java:301)
    at org.slf4j.impl@1.0.3.GA-redhat-2//org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Slf4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.slf4j@1.7.22.redhat-2//org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:366)
    at org.slf4j@1.7.22.redhat-2//org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:391)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-back.war//es.caib.accfor.presentation.back.security.SecurityBean.<init>(SecurityBean.java:34)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor124.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
   ...
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.cdi.ManagedPropertyProducer.evaluateExpressionGet(ManagedPropertyProducer.java:111)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.cdi.ManagedPropertyProducer.lambda$new$0(ManagedPropertyProducer.java:83)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiProducer.create(CdiProducer.java:128)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.cdi.ManagedPropertyProducer.create(ManagedPropertyProducer.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:700)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:800)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:336)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:347)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:700)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
```

**SecurityBean**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityBean implements Serializable {

    public static final String USER = "user";
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()); //Error
...
```

**pom.xml** dependencies that could be related

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-8.0</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

**Effecctive pom.xml**

```
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j-stub</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final-redhat-3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.GA-redhat-00001</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22.redhat-2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
```

Comment: try getClass().getSimpleName()

Comment: Maybe it is related with these points
1. The scope for slf4j-api should be "provided".  Simply referencing an slf4j logger within the java code will cause WildFly logging will use the slf4j api.

2. The default slf4j binding for WildFly is slf4j-jboss-logmanager.  If there is a desire to use a different binding, the binding must be set to "compile" scope.  Would this override the default slf4j-jboss-logmanager binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't kwow why the log doesn't show any problem with jsf beans but the problem was that have circular dependencies to each other with injections @ManagedProperty.
So the only I have to do is to make them independent.

**SecurityBean**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityBean {
...
   @Inject
   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionBean}")
      private SessionBean sessionBean;
..
```

**SessionBean**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean {
...
   @Inject
   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{securityBean}")
      private SessionBean sessionBean;
...
```